# Computing $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \log\left(-1+\frac1ni\right)$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \log\left(-1-\frac1ni\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

Computing $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \log\left(-1+\frac1ni\right)$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \log\left(-1-\frac1ni\right)$

I am fresman and self learning complex analysis.

ATTEMPT:

When $n$ goes to infity inside log goes to $-1$ in either way. But it is undefined.

So I try module $$\left | \log\left(-1+\frac1ni\right)\right|<??$$

So I have no clue to start?

Comment: You need a definition for the logarithm of a complex input. What is your definition?

Comment: When you've found your definition, you will see (most likely) that indeed $\log(-1)$ is not defined, but this doesn't mean that the limit doesn't exist. In fact both limits do exist, and they're different (assuming the standard definition of $\log$ which is also the one for which this exercise is relevant).

Answer (score 0):

We have that with reference to the principal value

$$-1+\frac1ni =\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}e^{i(\pi-\arctan\frac1n)} \to e^{i\pi}$$

$$-1-\frac1ni =\sqrt{1+\frac1{n^2}}e^{i(-\pi+\arctan\frac1n)} \to e^{-i\pi}$$

and therefore

$$\log\left(-1+\frac1ni\right)\to i\pi $$
$$\log\left(-1-\frac1ni\right)\to -i\pi $$

Comment: This is precisely the kind of thing that you would put a big red strike through on an exam paper. Where did this $k$ pop out from?